# Return html page as a result of a form sent with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send a form with AJAX and insert in a tag div the resulted html page. Each time I click the submit button, the page where there is the form is refreshed (This thing shouldn't happen with AJAX from what I've understood) and I don't have any result.

Looking around I found different solution with javascript but, because of I'm trying to learn AJAX, I'd like to know where I made mistakes.

Here the html code:

```
<form action="book.php" id="infoPrn">
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="name"></p>
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="email"></p>
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Tel" name="tel"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" role="button" value="Book"></p>
</form>
```

Here the jquery code:

```
<script >
    $("#infoPrn").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $("#infoPrn").serialize(), 
                    url: 'book.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                      $(".confirm").html(data);
                    }
            });
        }); 
</script>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX is fine, and your form submission works fine as well. What you have forgotten is to simply create a `<div>` to contain your **output**:

```
<div class="confirm"></div>
```

This `<div>` will be initially blank, and will get populated with the contents of `book.php` once the form is submitted.

Here is the full code:

```
<form action="book.php" id="infoPrn">
  <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="name"></p>
  <p><input type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="email"></p>
  <p><input type="text" placeholder="Tel" name="tel"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" role="button" value="Book"></p>
</form>
<div class="confirm"></div>

<script>
  $("#infoPrn").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: $("#infoPrn").serialize(),
      url: 'book.php',
      success: function(data) {
        $(".confirm").html(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks Obsidian Age for your answer. Actually I have the div which contain the result of the ajax request. I didn't add it on my question (sorry for that). I think there is something else wrong in the code  because the strange thing is that the page is refreshed when I click the button and I think this shouldn't happen.

Comment: No worries! The `e.preventDefault()` will prevent your 'default' form submission (and subsequent refresh). I've tested the above code locally, and it works as expected; your problem must be somewhere else. And the problem is definitely that **your jQuery isn't triggering**. Are you sure you have **included the jQuery library**? And there's no errors in the console? Another possibility is that you have your custom script in a different file, which is referenced incorrectly. Maybe try a simple `$(document).ready(function() { alert('Hi'); })` and see if that works by itself :)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the JQuery library is included, I use other scripts in different parts of the page. I tried to remove e.preventDefault() instruction to avoid the refresh and to try to debug the script, but the page refresh anyway. I also commented the ajax call and I added the simple script that you suggested. The popup appears, so the jQuery is triggered, but after I click ok on the popup windows the page is refreshed. :(. Any Ideas?